# Как лучше оформить неисчерпывающий перечень?

Tags: оформление-текста, корректура

Первый вариант.

> Текст, предваряющий перечень:
>
> первый элемент;
>
> второй элемент;
>
> третий элемент;
>
> и многое другое...

Второй вариант.

> Текст, предваряющий перечень:
>
> первый элемент;
>
> второй элемент;
>
> третий элемент;
>
> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба ваши варианта оформления *незаконченного перечня* неверны.
Считаю, что должно быть так.

> Текст, предваряющий перечень:
>    первый элемент;
>    второй элемент;
>    третий элемент и многое другое.

1. Если в конце списка стоит ***и др., и т. д.*** или ***и т. п.***, то такой текст не располагают на отдельной строке, а оставляют в конце предыдущего элемента списка.
2. Ромбик от текста отделяется пробелом.
3. Для сведения. Если части перечня (первый элемент, второй элемент, третий элемент — понимаю, что это условность) состоят из простых словосочетаний или одного слова, они отделяются друг от друга запятыми.

[Правила оформления перечней](http://www.delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5276)

Comment: *...Но не будет ошибкой и постановка в подобных случаях после абзацев точки с запятой...* ([Перечни](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091338.html#id-2Перечни-243Знакипрепинанияпослеабзацев–элементовперечня))

Comment: Конечно, не будет. Я ведь и оставила в конце каждой строки Вашего примера точку с запятой (только пояснила отдельно: _для сведения..._ Вдруг — там только по одному-два слова на строке?).  P. S. Что-то ответ мой каким-то блёклым получился. Всё ли другим участникам понятно? Может, стоит "понавыделять" основное место? Как Вы считаете?

Comment: Выделите рассматриваемый текстовый фрагмент в цитату, как в вопросе. В остальном, по мне, всё в порядке.